# Is there a reason to have both tox.ini and setup.cfg in a python project?

Tags: setuptools, tox, pyscaffold

I have just scaffolded a python project using PyScaffold. One thing that has caught my attention was the fact that the scaffolding generated both setup.cfg and tox.ini files. If my understanding is correct, if I were to use tox using the `tox` command, it would just look at the tox.ini file and ignore setup.cfg and setup.py altogether.

With this being the case, here is my question: is there a reason to keep both of them in the project, or would just using tox.ini or setup.cfg be enough? And if I have to keep both of them in my project, is there an easy way so both of them use the same configurations (e.g. configurations for running flake8 for linting) without me having to type those configurations in both setup.cfg and tox.ini?

Comment: `setup.cfg`/`setup.py` are for `setuptools`. `tox.ini` is for `tox`. Different tools, different configs.

Comment: That part I got - I guess what I indirectly wanted to ask was whether I need both tox and setuptools - to my untrained eye, they seem to be doing very similar things

Comment: I don't see any similarities. `setup.cfg`/`setup.py` are for building distributions, `tox.ini` is for running tests in on-the-fly created virtual environments; `tox` of course uses `setuptools` to build a distribution and install it into these virtual environments before running tests.

Comment: Ah, that was the missing link - I thought they were both used for building, and testing - thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Let's go through this step by step.

`PyScaffold` is a tool which tries to ease the setup of a new Python project.

What even is a Python project?

At the very heart a single executable Python file is enough.

If you want to make the project being installable, you need configuration file for the build system.

While a lot has changed over time, still `setup.py` is the most prominent one. At some point in time it was figured out, that it may be not such a great idea that the build configuration file could execute arbitrary code, so `setup.cfg` was invented, where you can define e.g. the projects name and dependencies in a ini-style format. Meanwhile, another format was invented, the `pyproject.toml` file.

So basically, to build your project you need one of those:

- setup.py
- setup.py and setup.cfg (the former only calls the latter)
- pyproject.toml

Usually you want to write tests for your project. You could use the builtin `unittest` testrunner to run your tests, or nowadays many projects use `pytest`. `pytest` can be configured with a `pytest.ini`.

Tests usually need some dependencies, e.g. `pytest` itself and maybe some other test helpers. They need to be installed at some time.

And here comes `tox` into play. Amongst many other features, like e.g. running your tests against different Python versions, `tox` can both install your project and your test requirements and execute the tests. `tox` usually comes with a `tox.ini` file.

Oh, and what about linting? You want to have easy to read code and follow the Python guidelines (e.g. PEP 8), so you usually use a tool like `flake8` - which also comes with its own configuration file, namely `.flake8`.

Ok, now we have many tools and many configuration files, but that's not all. As not everybody likes so many configuration files, some of the tools support to be configured with other tools's configuration file.

e.g. you can configure `flake8` both in a `setup.cfg` and a `tox.ini`, see https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html

You can also configure `tox` via `setup.cfg` or `pyproject.toml`, see https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#configuration-discovery

And one important thing to know: You only need to configure your tool once, not in all those files.

So, technically, you do not need all those files, and it is up to you what you think is an easy to read and easy to manage setup for your project.

At a past **Python Ireland** meetup I gave a 5 minute lightning talk about how this is all confusing and what solution I came up with:

https://youtu.be/8iqhNbDHC-c

Comment: That was a very detailed, awesome answer! Thank you so much, and special thanks for the video. This will make my pre-commit process so much easier

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and glad I could help!